# In Scala, why does a type annotation must follow for the function parameters ? Why does the compiler not infer the function parameter types?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a simple question, why is the Scala compiler not able to infer the function parameter types by itself ?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please try to give a more precise case, with specific examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Some functional programming languages, like Haskell, can infer almost
>   all types, because they can perform global type inference. Scala can’t
>   do this, in part because Scala has to support subtype polymorphism
>   (inheritance), which makes type inference much harder. Here is a
>   summary of the rules for when explicit type annotations are required
>   in Scala.

**When Explicit Type Annotations Are Required**

In practical terms, you have to provide explicit type annotations for the following situations:

- A mutable var or immutable val declaration where you don’t assign a value, (e.g., abstract declarations in a class like val book: String, var count: Int
- All method parameters (e.g., def deposit(amount: Money) = {…}).
- Method return types in the following cases:

  1)When you explicitly call return in a method (even at the end).

  2)When a method is recursive.

  3)When two or more methods are overloaded (have the same name) and one of them calls another; the calling method needs a return type annotation.

  4)When the inferred return type would be more general than you intended, e.g., Any.

Source [Programming Scala, 2nd Edition - O'Reilly Media](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033073.do)

Comment: Thanks ! That helped.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a simple question, why is the Scala compiler not able to infer the function parameter types by itself ?

Scala has local type inference. If you look at the method, and look at what information is there locally, it should be easy to see, that there simply *is no information* about what the types could possibly be.

Say, you have the following method:

```
def foo(a) = a + a
```

How is Scala going to figure out what type `a` is? It can only figure that out from looking at how the method is *called*, but that is *non-local* information!

And even worse: since Scala supports dynamic code loading, it is possible that the calling code *doesn't even exist yet* at compile time.